# this.$el undefined when writing typescript plugin

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I am a newbie in JavaScript. Here I want to create a module that enables customised attribute and related behaviour.

First, at the start of customised.ts I import Directive and ElementRef while I have Jquery imported at main.ts. Therefore I include [customised.ts] only

```
import {Directive, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
declare var jQuery: any;

@Directive ({
  selector: '[customised]'
})
```

The following code is to export class, and problem is when I call this.$el within the event listener function, the this.$el will be undefined.

```
export class ClearInput {
  $el: any;

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.$el = jQuery(el.nativeElement);
  }


  render():void {
    let toggleClass = (variable) => {
      return variable ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass';
    };

    this.$el.addClass('customised')
    .bind('input', function() {
      this.$el[toggleClass(this.$el.val())]('x');
    })
    .on('mousemove', function(e) {
      if(this.$el.hasClass('x')) { // error
        this.$el[toggleClass(this.$el.val())]('onX');
      }
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.render();
  }
}
```

The question is:

1. why this.$el.addClass will be executed twice?
2. why this.$el under "if" control flow is undefined, then it throw an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this.$el** is undefined because **this** is most likely changed by jquery when calling the **mousemove** listener.

If you want to keep the same context in the listener you can use an arrow function instead.

```js
.on('mousemove', e => {
  if (this.$el.hasClass('x')) {
    this.$el[toggleClass(this.$el.val())]('onX');
  }
})
```

As to why **addClass** is executed twice, maybe the **render** function is executed twice?

Comment: Thanks. I take a bit of careful when using arrow function. If the expression under if control flow is:  this.$el[toggleClass(this.offsetWidth)]('onX'); Then this.offsetWidth will not work as expected. How would this be improved?

Comment: well, one thing I would do is stop using jquery. Angular2 provides you with ways to handle clicks on elements, try to use those. Otherwise you'll have to do it the old way use regular functions and save $this.el in a local variable inside render.

Comment: Awesome! This is surely not good practice to write js code into angular2 project. But when some of the previous works of js plugins migrate to angular2 it is much time-saving by assigning "let self = this.$el" then using arrow functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.$el = jQuery(el.nativeElement);
  }
```

to

```
  ngAfterViewInit(el: ElementRef) {
    this.$el = jQuery(el.nativeElement);
  }
```